# Zend Framework choose controller from Plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, controller

Is it possible to choose controller from Plugin?

For example I have table of departments and categories in database. I'm fetching them and want to make certain actions(picking controller and action).

The reason - I don't want to create sepparate controller for each department and action for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following:

```
class Content_Plugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
  public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
    // fetching departments and categories
    // ...

    $request->setControllerName('my'); // will map class MyController
    $request->setActionName('special');  // will map MyController::specialAction();
  }
}
```